# Delete files older than 15 days if exist in another directory

Tags: shell-script

I have two folders: "/media/downloads/" and "/home/uploads/"
I want to delete the files older than 15 on "/media/downloads/" if exist in "/home/uploads/"

What is the best script to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
cd /home/uploads
uploaded_files=( **/*(ND.) )
cd /media/downloads
old_downloads=( **/*(ND.m+14) )
echo rm -- ${old_downloads:*uploaded_files}
```

(remove the `echo` to actually remove the files).

That would remove regular files 15 days old or older on `/media/downloads` if a regular file by the same path exits in `/home/uploads`. Note that it doesn't check whether they have the same contents.

As a script, that could look like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
die() {
  print -ru2 -C1 -- "$@"
  exit 1
}

usage() {
  die "$@" "Usage: $ZSH_SCRIPT:t [-d <days>] [-n] <srcdir> <dstdir>"       \
  ''                                                                \
  '  Removes files from <srcdir> if their age rounded down to an'   \
  '  integer number of days is strictly greater than <days> (14 by' \
  '  default). -n for dry-run'
  exit 1
}

zmodload zsh/system || die

dryrun=0 days=14
while getopts nd: o; do
  case $o in
    (n) dryrun=1;;
    (d) days=$OPTARG;;
    (*) usage;;
  esac
done

shift OPTIND-1
(( $# == 2 )) || usage
[[ $days = <0-> ]] || usage "$days is not a positive decimal integer"

src=$1 dst=$2

[[ -d $src ]] || die "$src is not a directory"
[[ -d $dst ]] || die "$dst is not a directory"

list() {
  local dir=$1 var=$2 qual=$3 err
  ERRNO=0
  () { eval $var'=( "${@#$dir/}" )'; } $dir/**/*(ND.$qual)
  if (( ERRNO )); then
    syserror -e err
    die "An error was encountered during $dir traversal: $err"
  fi
}

list $src old_in_src m+$days
list $dst all_in_dst oN
to_remove=( ${old_in_src:*all_in_dst} )

if (( dryrun )); then
  if (( $#to_remove )); then
    print -ru2 -C1 "$#old_in_src old files found in $src, out of which $#to_remove are also found in $dst:" ' - '$^to_remove
  else
    print -ru2 "No file found to remove ($#old_in_src old files in $src in total)"
  fi
else
  rm -f -- $src/$^to_remove
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first script but It gave me "rm:missing operand". I enteres rm -f and I think now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` and `bash`:

```
find /media/downloads/ -type f -mtime +15 \
  -exec bash -c 'for f; do
                   f2=${f/"/media/downloads/"/}
                   test -e "/home/uploads/$f2" && delfiles+=("$f");
                 done;
                 [ -n "$delfiles" ] && printf "rm %q\n" -- "${delfiles[@]}"' bash {} +
```

`find` finds all regular files older than 15 days¹ and passes them as args to `bash`.  For each filename, bash strips the top-level directory (`/media/downloads/`) from the filename, then checks to see if the remainder of the filename (including sub-directory, if any) exists under `/home/uploads/`.  If it does, then it adds the file to an array called `$delfiles`.

Once it has iterated over all filename args, it prints each filename in the array.

This is written as a dry-run, so it will only **show** what it would do without actually doing it.  To make it actually delete the files, change `printf "rm %q\n" --` to `rm --`

It won't ever delete any directories, even if they're empty after their contents have been deleted.  If you need to do that, you could run something like the following (using GNU find) after deleting the files.

```
find /media/downloads/ -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

Also worth noting: both `zsh` and `ksh` have similar parameter expansion & string modification capabilities, so it should be trivial to use either `zsh` or `ksh` instead of bash (probably only needing to change `bash -c` to `ksh -c` or `zsh -c` but I haven't tested that, so can't say for sure - there may be subtle differences between bash and those shells).

---

**¹** see `man find` and search for `-atime` for details on how that is calculated - you may find that `-mtime 14` works better for you.  find's `-daystart` option may also be if interest.

Comment: ITYM `printf "rm -- %q\n"` rather than `printf "rm %q\n" --`

Comment: According to the man page for GNU find, `-delete` implies `-depth`: *"The  use  of  the  -delete action on the command line automatically turns on the -depth option."*